# Can たり be used without する at the end?

Tags: grammar, renyōkei

http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/compound#part8 explains what たりする is.

I read "地面が４０ｃｍ以上高くなったり、１ｍ２０ｃｍ以上低くなった所もありました" on http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10010492331000/k10010492331000.html
I recognized たり, but it differs from たりする grammar that I learned.

How should I understand the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. たり is traditionally used as AしたりBしたりする, but some people (including professional writers) occasionally use it as AしたりBする to avoid repetition (some people treat this as wrong, though). Their meanings are exactly the same.

Comment: If you look at the sentence, there is no する at the end. How can you explain the lack of する?

Comment: Ａなったり、Ｂなったりした　→　Ａなったり、Ｂなった
The final たり and accompanying する have been merged into a conjugated なる which parallels the first.