# 「それらを習得したり磨くことより、うまく合わせて使うことが一番難しい」- Shouldn't this be 習得したり磨いたりすることより～

Tags: grammar

> それらを習得したり磨くことより、うまく合わせて使うことが一番難しい

Making them go smoothly and using them is harder than learning them and polishing them.

- Wouldn't this make sense if it were 習得したり磨いたりすることより～ ?
- I've read that if たりする isn't the last segment of the sentence, する can be omitted, but if that is the case, shouldn't it be

> 習得したり磨いたりことより～

I think this link is related to it though [Can たり be used without する at the end?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/34087/46733)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Wouldn't this make sense if it were 習得したり磨いたりすることより～ ?

Yes. Actually it is usually taught that  [repeating たり is more proper.](https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/gimon/154.html), although the second たり is frequently omitted. There is no difference in meaning depending on its presence.

> shouldn't it be 習得したり磨いたりことより～

No, this is ungrammatical. It is rather the opposite: If it **is** the last element of a sentence, する can be omitted.

An example:

- きのう何してた？ What did you do yesterday?
- ただゴロゴロしたりテレビみたり. Just lying around or watching TV.

"テレビ見たり**してた**" is cut short here. (I'm wondering if *lying around* can really mean ゴロゴロする.)